# handling SQL lite databases in adobe flash (air) for android

Tags: android, sqlite, flash, air

I want to develop an app using Adobe flash for android. I was wondering if I could use databases in it. That is a must for the app. I am pretty good with adobe flash already. But:
Is it possible to develop an app that is built in adobe air using adobe flash that implements database read/write actions for sqlite in android?

Answer (score 0):

While building a mobile app, Adobe AIR does not have any built in capabilites for working with any SQL server.

It does, however, have great capabilities to call out web services. So in order to work with a database engine, you will have to implement a server with some kind of service provider for HTTP or SOAP requests sent from your AIR application.

Another option is to use internal data structures that you can save on the device, such as data tables. But per your question, these are not SQL structures.